# How can I use commas inside a csv column to separate multiple floating point values?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, audio, wav

I have a question that is closely related to this question here:

[How to convert .wav files into a Pandas DataFrame in order to feed it to a neural network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54701792/how-to-convert-wav-files-into-a-pandas-dataframe-in-order-to-feed-it-to-a-neura)

I have created a pandas DataFrame with the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"wavsamples": pd.Series(wavsamples), "wavsamplerate": pd.Series(wavsamplerate), "wavname": pd.Series(wavname)}, copy=False, columns = ['wavsamples','wavsamplerate','wavname'])
df.index.name = 'filenumber'
```

If I print the second column inside my pandas DataFrame

with

```
print(df.wavsamples.to_string(index=False))
```

it shows me the pandas series 'wavsamples' that looks like this:

```
[0.02709961, 0.06796265, -0.011810303, -0.23361...
[0.0068969727, 0.04547119, 0.043029785, -0.1025...
[-0.005432129, 0.021057129, 0.078063965, 0.0270...
[0.00079345703, 0.064941406, 0.09710693, -0.088...
[-0.0067749023, 0.008087158, 0.06536865, 0.0219...
[-0.008758545, 0.015106201, 0.08139038, 0.02600...
[-0.0034179688, 0.039733887, 0.07711792, 0.1164...
[-0.0008087158, -0.000579834, -0.00062561035, -...
[0.021026611, 0.029907227, 0.040527344, 0.05448...
[0.017288208, 0.026321411, 0.0340271, 0.0403137...
[0.019561768, 0.026611328, 0.03668213, 0.047576...
[0.022827148, 0.03414917, 0.056289673, 0.078018...
```

Each of these 12 rows represents the raw floating point sample values of a .wav file. Now if I write these arrays inside a column of a CSV-file with:

```
df.to_csv("./test.csv", sep=',', columns = ['wavsamples','wavsamplerate','wavname'])
```

I get the following csv file:

```
filenumber,wavsamples,wavsamplerate,wavname
0,"[ 0.02709961  0.06796265 -0.0118103  ... -0.36627197 -0.36645508
 -0.3657837 ]",44100,Audio1.wav
1,"[ 0.00689697  0.04547119  0.04302979 ... -0.03359985 -0.03244019
 -0.03167725]",44100,Audio2.wav
2,"[-0.00543213  0.02105713  0.07806396 ...  0.45645142  0.45541382
  0.45510864]",44100,Audio3.wav
3,[0.00079346 0.06494141 0.09710693 ... 0.22116089 0.22421265 0.22741699],44100,Audio4.wav
4,"[-0.0067749   0.00808716  0.06536865 ...  0.24209595  0.23977661
  0.23754883]",44100,Audio5.wav
5,"[-0.00875854  0.0151062   0.08139038 ... -0.0256958  -0.0184021
 -0.01156616]",44100,Audio6.wav
6,"[-0.00341797  0.03973389  0.07711792 ...  0.41384888  0.41375732
  0.41348267]",44100,Audio7.wav
7,"[-0.00080872 -0.00057983 -0.00062561 ...  0.0100708   0.0100708
  0.01000977]",44100,Audio8.wav
8,[0.02102661 0.02990723 0.04052734 ... 0.00976562 0.00965881 0.00990295],44100,Audio9.wav
9,[0.01728821 0.02632141 0.0340271  ... 0.01344299 0.01341248 0.01325989],44100,Audio10.wav
10,[0.01956177 0.02661133 0.03668213 ... 0.0141449  0.01400757 0.01402283],44100,Audio11.wav
11,[0.02282715 0.03414917 0.05628967 ... 0.01019287 0.01037598 0.01025391],44100,Audio12.wav
```

So the column 'wavsamples' lost all of its commas. If I now read and print the column from the csv file with:

```
with open("./test.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    rows = list(reader)
    audiofile = rows[12][1]
    print(audiofile)
```

I just get:

`[0.02282715 0.03414917 0.05628967 ... 0.01019287 0.01037598 0.01025391]`

Not only have all the commas been removed, but as the wavsamples column gets treated like a character string the three dots get mistaken as literal dot characters so all the sample values in between get lost when writing them into the csv ...

I know that csv is possibly the worst format to store .wav data like pointed out a lot of times here on stack overflow ... but I'm just curious - is there any way to store audio arrays with commas between the floating point values inside a csv column?

I want to get a result like this when I read something from the csv:

```
[0.022827148, 0.03414917, 0.056289673, 0.078018...
```

Instead of this:

```
[0.02282715 0.03414917 0.05628967 ... 0.01019287 0.01037598 0.01025391]
```

How could I write the csv column so that I could read it correctly afterwards?

Comment: No, list values are not valid in CSV format. Given that you are dumping a column (as part of the larger dataframe) that doesn't contain scalar data, `pandas` will automatically cast it to string.

Comment: have you tried using a different `sep` character, like `|`?

Comment: If you really _have_ to stick with CSV format then you could probably use `apply` with `ast.literal_eval()` on the column after reading it back in. Or you need to pick a different format such as `parquet` which will be much more efficient anyway. If you were using `polars` instead, it would roundly reject you writing your current df to CSV, even though it actually has [first-class support for `List` types](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/user-guide/expressions/lists/) - it won't do this implicit cast

Comment: I may as well make that the answer I guess...

Comment: Perhaps you might want to save that data as a list of json objects. That would allow you to have values as actual lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSV format will not support list types in a column, you need scalar values. What happens here is that `pandas` will implicitly cast that column containing the list type to a string. It has nothing to do with your chosen delimiter.

One possible way to handle this if you *have* to have CSV format is to parse it back to a list type using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), to be applied across that column, when you read the data back in.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]],
                   'b': [4, 5, 6]})
print(df.head())

df.to_csv('nested_test.csv', index=False)

df = pd.read_csv('nested_test.csv')
print(df.head()

for _, row in df.iterrows():
    # Note that, though it *looked* like a list in df.head()
    # we just get [ printed, as the first character of the
    # string it actually is
    print(row['a'][0]) 
      
import ast  
df['a'] = df['a'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

for _, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row['a'][0]) # Now we get the first item in the list
```

If you used `polars` instead of `pandas`, this implicit cast would not be allowed and it would throw an exception. This is despite the fact that [it has a `List` type as a first-class citizen](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/user-guide/expressions/lists/). For this kind of data, you really should be looking into a format such as `parquet`, which is not only *many times faster* to parse in, but will natively handle the nested structure of your column(s).

Finally, in your question, you specify using the `csv` module to read the data back in. You can do this, but I don't suppose it's particularly elegant, given the restrictions on CSV that I mentioned. This works for the example I gave, which assumes that all other non-list columns will be `int`, otherwise you'll need to handle them one-by-one.

```
import csv

with open('nested_test.csv') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    headers = next(reader)
    rebuilt = []
    for row in reader:
        rebuilt.extend([ast.literal_eval(row[0]), *map(int, row[1:])])
    print(rebuilt)
```

---

Just to complicate things further, you don't actually have lists in your column but actually `np.ndarray` objects. When they get converted to strings, you lose the commas from `__repr__` on top of the other complications.

```
arr = np.array([1., 2., 3.])
print(arr)
```

Save yourself an extra headache by using:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].apply(np.ndarray.tolist)
```

*before* `df.to_csv()`

... you might now be seeing why CSV is not a great format here ...

Comment: If I use your code like this:
`df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')  
df['wavsamples'] = df['wavsamples'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row['wavsamples'][0]) # Now we get the first item in the list`

I get the following error:
`[ 0.02709961  0.06796265 -0.0118103  ... -0.36627197 -0.36645508
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?`

I think the df.to_csv is the main problem here because the values can't be read at all afterwards as they are not getting written correctly in the first place ...

Comment: Parquet really works like a charm by the way

Comment: Ooo, fancy. That's the literal representation of a numpy array instead of a list. I'll see if I can account for that

Comment: @Laulito edited to fix

Comment: df['wavsamples'] = df['wavsamples'].apply(np.ndarray.tolist) is exactly what was missing here!

Now it creates a huge csv file with basically EVERY single wave sample from the .wav files! 

Yes, using parquet like this:
df.to_parquet('df.parquet.gzip', compression='gzip')  

Is a lot more convenient, as it compresses the data and still allows to use it afterwards without any problem. But like I've said I was just asking out of pure curiosity if there would be any possibility to store .wav in a csv. Turns out there is. Thanks a lot for your time and effort @roganjosh! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
df['wavsamples'] = df['wavsamples'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(map(str, x)))
```

for more info check this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = {'Values': [np.array([0.02709961, 0.06796265, -0.0118103, -0.36627197, -0.36645508, -0.3657837])]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# Converting the NumPy array to a comma-separated string
df['Values'] = df['Values'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(map(str, x)))
print(df)
```

Comment: Does not work. If I create the csv like this, the column 'wavsamples' is completely empty.

Comment: @Laulito I have edited it you can use this now!!

Comment: Thank you @Nikhil S! Your edited solution works as well! Putting df['wavsamples'] = df['wavsamples'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(map(str, x))) before df.to_csv inserts commas in between the floating point values, just like I was asking about originally!

With your edited code the column "wavsamples" now stores a huge number of values inside, representing the wave file sample data. Thank you for your solution!